# Calling one jsp from another jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 machines running tomcat which are in lan.

Can I make a call from jsp in one machine to another jsp page in another machine

I have tried it as follows:

```
<%
  RequestDispatcher rd=application.getRequestDispatcher("http://10.44.111.149:8080/stud/sample.jsp");
  RequestDispatcher rd=application.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
  rd.include(request,response);
%>
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path http://10.44.111.149:8080/stud/sample.jsp does not start with a "/" character
```

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Start by reading the javadoc of `getRequestDispatcher`.

Comment: You wrongly understood `getRequestDispatcher`.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this apart from `getRequestDispatcher`

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the client to any URL on the internet (not with `getRequestDispatcher` though), but the JSP that handles that redirect will not have any of the servlet/request/session context that was generated by the first machine (unless you're clustering web servers with cross-server sessions).

Answer (score 0):

RequestDispatcher is not intended for such an use. Instead you can use response.sendRedirect(...) from your server to the remote server as below

```
response.sendRedirect(remoteServerUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there any way I can set a header which can be accessed by the `remoteServerUrl`. I tried setting `response.setHeader("USER", "test");` but did not work.

Comment: Do you just want to send some parameter across to the remote url ? If that is the case you can just send it along as remoteServerUrl + "?user=test" with the sendRedirect call"

Comment: Bu my jsp accepts values only in this format `String HeaderValue = request.getHeader("USER"); ` So in order to get the value on server end how do I need to set the value before sendRedirect.

Comment: you can access it as request.getParameter("user"); in you jsp. However if you are planning to send sensitive information via the URL it may not be a wise idea.

Comment: I'm just trying to find out is there a way to do it so than my jsp page gets a value when it does `String HeaderValue = request.getHeader("USER");`